# How to parse a file in JavaCC

Tags: javacc

I started using JavaCC a few days ago.. I am looking for a good tutorial. 
how to parse a .dat file?

In my first example the program ask me to enter an expression then says if it's ok or not! but if I want the program to read file then parse it?!

Thank you!

Comment: Is your problem that you know what a .dat file should look like but you are having trouble expressing this in JavaCC or is your problem that you don't know the structure of a .dat file?  If the former you should make your question specific. If the latter, it's not really a JavaCC question. Speaking for myself I have no idea what a .dat file is.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for your response. 
I resolved this problem! a.dat file look likes a text file where I can store some values ... 
But I have another problem.. 
Let me explain my project. 
I have a text file of a lot of lines and each one contains 3 or 4 value separate with a space. I have to read this value and overwrite them in another text file. The problem is that the numbers are real of the form 1235.215E6 .. I don't know how to declare such as a variable!